# PHP date/time to timestamp (custom format)

Tags: php, windows, datetime, format

Any one got a function to like `strtotime()` but the takes the format as input?

For example I need to convert `yyyymmdd` to a timestamp, or perhaps `yyyyddmm`. So I would like to specify the format used. Also Im on **Windows** so `strptime()` isn't an option.

Comment: some one write it for windows http://sauron.lionel.free.fr/?page=php_lib_strptime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP 5's `DateTime` class has the [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method which does what you need.

However, it requires PHP 5.3 so it's not always an option (yet).

Comment: PHP 5.3.3 is the ONLY option. :D

Comment: @Petah in that case, it'll work for you, it will create a `DateTime` object. You can easily convert that into a timestamp (although the `DateTime` class is great to work with as well)

Answer (score -1):

Very easy to write a function, just take a look at [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)...

```
// Assumes yyyy-mm-dd
function fromdate($date) {
    $d = explode("-", $date);
    return mktime(0, 0, 0, $d[1], $d[2], $d[0]);
}
```